# VBA "Invalid Qualifier Error"

Tags: excel, vba

Getting an Invalid Qualifier Error on this code, have no idea why.

```
Dim WTotal As Integer
WTotal = InputBox("Enter the amount of Wash")
Dim Startpoint As Range
Dim totalamount As Integer

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Set Startpoint = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Wash")
Startpoint.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
totalamount = Selection.Count

MsgBox "totalamount = " & totalamount.Value
```

This part shows up as the cause of the Error

MsgBox "totalamount = " & **totalamount**.Value

Comment: it's `MsgBox "totalamount = " & totalamount` only without `.value`

Answer (score 8):

Totalamount is an integer - it is not an object. An object is something like a range (ie: sheets(1).Range("A1")). Objects have properties, such as the value property. In this case, all you need is

```
MsgBox "totalamount = " & totalamount
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `.Value` from `totalAmount.Value`.

`totalAmount` is a variable of primitive type and primitive variables have no methods.

```
Dim WTotal As Integer
WTotal = InputBox("Enter the amount of Wash")
Dim Startpoint As Range
Dim totalamount As Integer

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Set Startpoint = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Wash")
Startpoint.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
totalamount = Selection.Count

MsgBox "totalamount = " & totalamount
```